# Google API won't recognize my ip

Tags: c#, api, google-api, ip, api-key

So I have a Google API project. I've written a C# program to connect with it using a Public access API key. When the API key is not restricted to a particular IP address, the program works. However, when I restrict the API key to the IP address of my server, like so:
[image]

I get a ip blocked error, like so:

[image: IP blocked error]

I confirmed that this is the IP of my machine in two ways. I went to whatsmyip.com and got this:

[image]

and I wrote a little php program on another server and called it via another console app to get the REMOTE_ADDR:

[image]

According to every method I know to check, my IP address is ###.###.###.197. But when I put that IP in the key for server applications it says my IP is not allowed. I've also run the same program from other computers and put those computers' ip addresses in the server key and the program also worked.

Why is the Google api not recognizing the IP address of the machine at ###.###.###.197 even though I permitted that IP in the API key?

Comment: Have you regenerated the key after you added the IP addresses?

Comment: Yes, I regenerated the key. That was the first thing I tried. Should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

One idea: Can you modify your Google API project to tell you the client IP address that Google sees? I have never worked with Google API but I saw it can do geolocation and stuff like that, so I assume your Google-side code should be able to access that info. If your Google API project also sees the .197 IP address, then it's time to contact Google support ;-)

Comment: Sorry, this should have been a comment, not an answer, but I hope it helps.

Comment: It's a good suggestion. I have tried to find a way to do what you're saying, and I have not found a way to get that data from Google, either in the console or through the program. The Google API docs aren't the most transparent in the world. If anyone knows how to do that it would be a big help.